# Behavior of STUFF function for empty strings

Tags: sql-server, string-manipulation

When working on answering another question (on SO), I came across some unexpected (to me) behavior with the STUFF function.

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    'a', -- character expression
    1,  -- start
    1,  -- length
    'z' -- replaceWith_expression
)
```

returns `NULL`, while I would expect it to return 'z'.

> ## Stuff
>
> The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> `STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )`
>
> ### Remarks
>
> If the start position or the length is negative, or if the starting position is larger than length of the first string, a null string is returned. If the start position is 0, a null value is returned. If the length to delete is longer than the first string, it is deleted to the first character in the first string.
>
> An error is raised if the resulting value is larger than the maximum supported by the return type.

Per the documentation, there are a number of reasons why a NULL string would be returned:

- If *start* is longer than the first *character_expression*
- If *start* is negative or 0
- If *length* is negative

Answer (score 1):

After closely reading the documentation while posting this question, I realized it told me the answer. I'm still posting it, since I hope it might be helpful to others in a similar predicament.

Per the documentation:

> If start is negative or zero, a null string is returned. If start is longer than the first character_expression, a null string is returned. start can be of type bigint.

This means that, effectively, you can't use `STUFF` with an empty string (since any argument to `start` will result in a NULL string).

One workaround is to use a non-empty string, and delete the content. For the above example, you could use `STUFF('a', 1, 1, 'z')` to delete the initial character.